# How to return all that doesn't exist in second table or exist with 'null' value

Tags: mysql, sql

**T1:**

```
ID   NAME
132  TOM
133  JEK
134  MAX
135  JIZ
```

**T2:**

```
ID      VALUE      CID
1       house      132
2       flat       133
3       'null'     135
```

ID from T1 = CID in T2

I need to return all NAMES that haven't records in T2 or have record but with 'null; in the VALUE column.
I tried this:

SELECT T1.name, T2.value
FROM T1 JOIN T2
ON T1.ID=T2.CID
WHERE T2.value='null'

That's works fine in case that record exist and have null value, but I need to return also all records that haven't records in T2, how I can customize/change my query?

Comment: What if there is are two rows in `t2` for the same id and one is `'null'` and one is not?

Comment: Then not need to return, I need only values that haven't records in T2 or have but with null

Comment: Real task is like: return all names that doesn't have home (no records for ID(CID) in T2), but also there is case when someone has home and then delete it, so there will be record in T2 but with 'null' in value

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to outer join the tables and return rows for `t1` where `t2` is null

```
select t1.*
from t1
left join t2 on t2.cid=t1.id and t2.value is not null
where t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want records in `t1` that are not in `t2`, think `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.cid = t.id);
```

If you want any row that either doesn't *or* the value is `'null'`, you can use:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.cid = t.id and t2.value <> 'null'
                 );
```

Comment: What is "select 1" and "from t t2"?

Comment: `1` is a number between 0 and 2.  It is an arbitrary choice, because `exists` checks for *rows* not columns.  `t t2` is assigning the alias `t2` to `t`.  But that is not needed, so I removed it.